# TextBox Events in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, validating

I have a TextBox. After leaving the textBox the first character should be a capital Letter.
Three Events work as same. They are Leave,Validating and Validated.

```
if (txtLocl.Text.Length > 0)
    txtLocl.Text = txtLocl.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + txtLocl.Text.Substring(1);
```

Which event of these 3 events should I use?

Comment: Better you can go with user control..........

Comment: Read this: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx), it might hold the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`Control.Leave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) event which will be fired when the control loses focus. Originally, I thought using [`Control.LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) would be the most appropriate event to use but it is not available via the designer meaning you would need to manually subscribe to the event which is a bit ugly and unconventional in my opinion.

```
private void inputTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inputTextBox.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        string input = inputTextBox.Text;
        inputTextBox.Text = input.First().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper() +
                            string.Join(string.Empty, input.Skip(1));
    }
}
```

You sound like you're interested in [`Control.Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx). The advantage of using `Control.Validating` is that you can utilize the event handler's given argument; `CancelEventArgs` and set the `Cancel` property to true. What this will do is stop the control from losing focus and forcing the user to enter a *valid* value. I don't think this is appropriate for your application as you are not really validating anything but formatting the input.

```
private void inputTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (inputTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "The given input is not valid.";
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that when the form closes, all controls subsequently lose focus and the `Control.Validating` event is fired which could stop the Form closing until all fields pass their relative validation checks. If you find yourself needing to avoid this behavior a quick search will prevail.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other events also available.

As said by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), by calling the Select or SelectNextControl methods, or by setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form, focus events occur in the following order:

```
1) Enter

2) GotFocus

3) Leave

4) Validating

5) Validated

6) LostFocus
```

When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus method, focus events occur in the following order:

```
1) Enter

2) GotFocus

3) LostFocus

4) Leave

5) Validating

6) Validated
```

If the CausesValidation property is set to false, the Validating and Validated events are suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

> textBox1_Leave is appropriate for you.

Check the events and description about textboxes over here>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Comment: I want to know what is the difference between them...,

Comment: @sreeaneev From what I can see, the difference lies merely in the order in which the events are called.

Comment: Leave event fires w/e control loses input focus. Validating and Validated fire only when validation takes place (there are multiple ways to suppress/disable validation of a control).

Comment: Thanks @Nik for additional and important info.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to subscribe to LostKeyboardFocus event (in WPF) or Leave event (in WF).

Comment: And from what jQuery version is that?

Comment: Im sorry? Isnt it a .Net related question? Oo

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Leave because I assume you aren't validating the value, but formatting it. Validating and Validated should contain code for validation and the aftermath of validation respectively, IMO.