# Event for TextBox AutoComplete changed

Tags: c#, textbox

I have two textboxes in my windows form named `txtUserName` and `txtPassword`, now I'm populating the `txtUserName` using the code

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection myCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
_userEMailList = UserCredentials.GetUserEmails();

foreach (var item in _userEMailList)
{
    myCollection.Add(item);
}

txtUserName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCollection;
```

where `UserCredentials.GetUserEmails()` method returns a `List<string>`.

Now the user will get suggestions and thus can select from one of the options.

So my problem is that when the user selects from one of the suggestion, the value of `txtPassword` should auto-fill. I have a method which takes EMail-ID as a parameter and returns the password. In web application, we can use `onblur` but as my code is part of a windows application, so `JavaScript` usage is not possible.

Comment: Did you write the code, you provided?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Yes, why?

Comment: Can you check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336928/textbox-events-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just check for a press of Enter. Selecting an item from autocomplete with the mouse will also trigger this:

```
private void txtUserName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) 
    {
        this.txtPassword.Text = GetPassword(this.txtUserName.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is not triggered in any of the cases mentioned.

Comment: But you did assign it to the event of the `TextBox`, right?

Comment: No. I'm new to C# so still figuring out how to do tasks. Now I got why you asked if I wrote that code or not :)

Comment: Ok, then in your designer select the `txtUserName` TextBox and got to events and set `KeyDown` event to this method.